# Ignore an optional prefix in expression

Tags: regex, optional-values

How can I get a string after a prefix that is optional? Example:

```
Expression    Result
------------------------
[asdf]xxx  => xxx
[foo]bar   => bar
[]bla      => bla
test       => test
```

`[...]` is the optional part.

Obviously, I need a look-around assertion. But I don't know hot to make it optional.

Comment: `\[.*?\](.*)`, first group is what you want, implementation depends on your language

Comment: @MarounMaroun: That doesn't make the `[...]` optional...

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? Lookaround is not fully supported by most engines.

Comment: Sorry. Updated my post to make it more precise.

Comment: @TimPietzcker missed the optional part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a modification of @Maroun's regex making the `[...]` optional:

```
(?:\[.*?\])?(.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hM2sK8/1

Notice how I put the first part in a *non-capturing group* and made it optional with the `?` after the group.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:\[[^\]]*\]\K)?.+$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/14

or

```
\[[^\]]*\](*SKIP)(*F)|.+$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/15

Comment: Still catches the part between `[]`

Comment: @funkwurm does not now

Comment: @vks   `[[^\]]*\]` i'm get confusion about it? This kind of output easily get by `(?:\[.*\]\K)?.+` . Can you explain `[[^\]]*\]` the part of code? Mainly i'm confused about the `^` character in your code?

Comment: @Hussain `\[.*\]` will grab upto last `]`.So if there are multiple `[]` then it capture upto last `]`.So we use negated `]` technique which states that capture aythingg starting `[` upto when it cannot find a `]` character i.e `[^\]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use

```
[^\[\]]*$
```

which matches any number of characters except brackets until the end of the string. It would also match `xxx` in `][]sd[][xxx`, though, so if you need to validate the structure of the string, this regex is not specific enough.

Comment: I agree. This passes all test cases shown and doesn't require (variously supported) look arounds. (I was going to answer this way too, but Tim out-drew me!)